# Preventing 2 users from updating the same record simultaneously

Tags: mysql, database, concurrency

I have a table `tbl_orders`. It has a quantity field `quantity`. 
In some part of my application I need to decrement the quantity by 1.

I already know the `id` of the record (available from the client side), so I issue an update statement:

```
UPDATE tbl_orders
SET quantity=quantity-1
WHERE id= 6
```

The problem is that this query can accidentally be run multiple times concurrently. 
For example, 2 customer service operators may update the same record simultaneously.
That means that the quantity will be decremented by 2 when it is supposed to be decremented once only.

I tried putting the update in a transaction, but that resulted in only delaying the second transaction until the first one was committed. Once it was committed the second update ran and decremented the record again.

How can I make sure that other queries fail if one is modifying a record?

**UPDATE:**

for an update to be valid the quantity on the client side was the same in the database. For example if a user sees a quantity 5 on his browser and wants to decrement it, the value in database must be the same.

**UPDATE 2**

I found a good explanation [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html#optimistic-locking) for optimistic locking using Doctrine 2:

Comment: This may not be a solvable problem on the database side, because presumably sometimes you'll *want* the quantity to be decremented by 2.  You need a foolproof way of telling when the multiple queries are an accident, and when they're on purpose.

Comment: How do you know when it is valid to allow the update to go through and when it is not? For example, what if the two users clicked the button milliseconds apart?

Comment: @D-Rock It is valid if the quantity on the client side was the same in the database. For example if a user sees a quantity 5 on his browser and wants to decrement it, the value in database must be the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One approach I've used/seen in the past was having a timestamp column.  When querying, ensure you have both the ID and the original timestamp at the start of editing the record.  Then, when you are trying to update, send via

```
update YourTable
   set counter = counter -1,
       TheTimestampColumn = new timestamp value
   where ID = yourID
     and TheTimeStampColumn = timeStampEditStartedWith
```

This way, whoever gets to it first with the original starting timestamp would win.  For the one following, you would have to track how many records were updated, and if that count equals zero, then you would notify the user that another person made a change to the record while you were viewing it.  Do you want to reload the latest data?  (or something like that).

Comment: @Songo, depends on if you are optimistic or not :)  but yes, you are anticipating that no two people are working on the record at the same time, yet not forcing an explicit LOCK to delay other activities.  More work / tracking / feedback to user.

Comment: @Songo Yep, and as a side note, using an `int` instead of a `timestamp` is another common way people do it.